# toggle between 2 layer sliders in drupal7 by language

Tags: drupal-7, slider

Is there any way to toggle between 2 layer sliders in multilingual drupal site? i need to replace sliders by language when i switch to english the english version of slider appears and so on, any help?

Comment: are you mean, you need to display defferant slider for each language ?

if yes, are you using view & content type to do this ?

Comment: yes that's what i mean, i am using blocks

Comment: i want to switch between 2 blocks by site's language

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thats good mate,

(This solution if you build or render a block from defferant place)

In your block you can find a Visibility settings, 
in Visibility settings you will find a Languages then checkbox for your Show this block for these languages

(if you need a one block & need to retrieve a current user language slider)
you go to your slider view - > FILTER CRITERIA --> add --> Content: Language --> check box on a Current user's language.

Note: you will be sure the content type is translatable, ([il8n drupal module](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) )